# How to pass parmeter from file to sqlplus in unix

Tags: sqlplus

I have file in which I have employee id and every number of employee id are different, which means that the count of employee id in the file are different every time. Example:

```
343535435
365765767
343534543
343543543
```

I want to pass this file to sqlplus.

The SQL command is

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE EMPLYOE_ID IN (ALL RECORDS FROM ABOVE FILE)
```

and I am calling this .sql file from unix via

```
$ sqlplus -s user/password@servername @.sql
```

Please let us know how I can pass above mentioned filename in unix to sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use SQL*Loader or external tables to load that file to a working table, named `work_table` in the example below, and then do a

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE EMPLYOE_ID IN (select EMPLYOE_ID from work_table);
```

Or if you don't have the time nor patience to do that, if you have control over the input file format, just put a comma after the end of each employee ID except for the last one, (assuming you have less than 256 IDs total),  and assuming the file is named `emp_input.txt` in the current directory:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE EMPLYOE_ID IN (
  @@emp_input.txt
  );
```

The contents of `emp_input.txt` are embedded via the `@@` if the file is in the same directory as the script that is running; in this case, you could probably use just one `@` character.

If whoever is creating the input file doesn't want to omit the comma on the last entry in the file, then you could include a bogus value in your query that would account for the trailing comma:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE EMPLYOE_ID IN (
  @@emp_input.txt
  -999999
  );
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I have no access in database to create external table, we have only read access

Comment: Then you could use the example above if you have control over the input file. You can use a full path to the file if you use a single `@` character: 


    @/home/user/emp_ids.txt

Comment: Hi Mark,  I use @ but it is giving error, missing expression, i use both @@ or @ way, same error

Comment: I would try starting sql*plus in interactive mode, do a 
     
    `set echo on`

invoke your script that has the select statement in it, then when you get the output, post it and we can see what is going on.

You may have to use the `list` command to show the generated SQL.